# Retrieve only the fields shown in userdisp.aspx from User Information List

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, wss-3.0, user-profile, user-accounts

I have built a Web Part in Visual Studio 2008 to show the current user's information (this is for WSS 3.0).

I have no problem iterating through all the fields in the SPListItem, but I want to filter out the fields that are NOT shown on the User Information page (_layouts/userdisp.aspx). I can't seem to identify the property to compare to. When I filter by Hidden = false, I still get SIP Address, Content Type, etc.

An explanation: When a user views their information from the user information list in one site collection, they see Account, Name, E-Mail, Job Title, About Me, etc.  In a different site collection, we have added Department, Code and Branch. I want to create a Web Part that shows the visible fields, so I can deploy it across all site collections without customizing.  One option is to make these fields required, and then filter by Required = true, but these are not necessarily required fields and I would have to edit every site collection for it to work.

Any suggestions on what property or properties to use? I used the WSS-3.0 tag for this question, as I think the answer would be different in SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: The solution I found also applies to getting the correct ViewFields for any list, it seems SPView.ViewFields does NOT reflect the fields that are defined in the browser, I am not sure why. The workaround is to define the local SPWeb object as such: SPWeb objWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that sharepoint gets this fields from one of the list view for user information list (Detail View I guess, I can't verify it exactly, because I always redirected to my host site). But you can check it:

```
var list = web.Lists["User Information List"];
var view = list.Views["Detail View"];
for (int i = 0; i < view.ViewFields.Count; i++)
{
     var fieldInternalName = view.ViewFields[i];
     ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kai! That sent me in the right direction, but here's a quirky thing: The viewfields are for the unedited detail view, the workaround I found was to replace web (the current web site, or SPContext.Current.Web) with this: 


SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl) Then it works as designed. I have to retrieve the SPField using the ViewField, but it works somewhat, almost, elegantly. Thanks again for the revelation.

Comment: This does meet my immediate need, which is to provide the site manager with a means of managing the fields shown in the web part without inventing a complicated method (like in the properties pane). However, the Details View does NOT match the userdisp.aspx form. If anyone has a solution to the original problem, I would like to hear it.

Comment: Try to check other views for user information list.